# React - this.props are undefined in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to map through the Users in App.js and show them in the User component, but when I pass the state down to User component through props, it shows props is undefined.

The weird thing is when I look in my react dev tools, I see that the users have props.details.

This is what the js console says.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'firstName' of 'this.props.details' as it is undefined.
```

App.js

```
// import './App.css';

    import React from "react";
    import Header from './components/Header';
    import User from './components/User';
    import AdminSection from './components/AdminSection';
    import users from './sampleData';
    class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
        users: {},
      }
      loadSampleUsers = () => {
        this.setState({ users: users });
      };
      addUser = user => {
        const users = { ...this.state.users }
        users[`user${Date.now()}`] = user;
        this.setState({
          users
        })
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.loadSampleUsers()
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
              <Header funTime="Alan's Header" /> 
            </header>
            <ul>
              {Object.keys(this.state.users).map(key => (
                  <User
                    key={key}
                    index={key}
                    details={this.state.users[key]}
                  />
              ))}
            </ul>
            <AdminSection users={this.state.users} addUser={this.addUser} />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    export default App;
```

User.js

```
import React from "react";
class User extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, dashboardAccess } = this.props.details;
    return (
      <div>
        {firstName}, {lastName}, {email}, {dashboardAccess}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default User;
```

sampleData.js
// sampleData.js

```
 const users = {
      user1: {
        firstName: "Alan",
        lastName: "Nubson",
        email: "alan@idmedia.ca",
        dashboardAccess: true,
      },
      user2: {
        firstName: "Scott",
        lastName: "Pasko",
        email: "scot@idmedia.ca",
        dashboardAccess: true,
      },
    }
    export default users;
```

UPDATE:
When I put in `{this.props.details && this.props.details.firstName}` it works.  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: maybe the details props is undefined like the error says. Did you try debugging if the details prop holds some value?

Comment: Can you add a console.log(this.props) inside user’s render method just before destructuring? I think your users object has some undefined keys

Comment: Also I would recommend you switching to an array when you have to store an arbitrary number of objects, it’s just better. Arrays come with many useful methods to find, filter sort etc that objects don’t have or are cumbersome to use.. Use objects only when the number of stuff you have to store is static

Comment: You have to deal with the render before the users are loaded.